# How to Disable brand logo and boot animation

Tags: boot, samsung-galaxy-grand, boot-animation

Hii Everyone I am using Samsung Galaxy Grand i9082 device and when i turn it on it is showing two screens one with model number and other with Samsung logo and boot animation is there any possibility to disable both the animations and display a blank screen until home screen appears

Comment: You can't change the model number one (in theory you can but I've never seen it done), the boot animation can be flashed in recovery on a rooted device. http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/change-android-boot-animation/

Answer (score 1):

You can delete `/system/media/bootanimation.zip` and the second boot animation would be gone. You need to root your phone to do that though. Also, this would make your home screen appear faster, but not fully functional until it competes boot.

Changing or removing the first boot splash is trickier, it requires recompiling the kernel with a blank boot splash and flashing that to the device - which is dangerous, hard and , as it requires you to unlock the bootloader, possibly void the warranty and it also runs a risk of bricking the phone.

Comment: I removed the bootanimation ("colored flying circles) , but now I see "android" text logo. How can I get rid of it ?

Comment: You can try setting/adding `debug.sf.nobootanimation = 1` to your `build.prop`